# Is there a link between blood pressure and salt intake?

Tags: environmental-health, public-health

So I was reading [Cracked article about health risk myths](http://www.cracked.com/article_21926_5-bs-health-myths-people-still-believe-thanks-to-one-guy.html). The first entry was interesting:

> [Myth #5] Salt Causes High Blood Pressure
>
> [...] Countless more recent studies have utterly failed to back up the relationship between salt intake and high blood pressure. [...] The truth is that science is still trying to figure out what causes high blood pressure -- maybe it is salt for some people, or just certain types of salt.

I followed the other links there:

- [New York Times: We only think we know the truth about salt](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/06/03/opinion/sunday/we-only-think-we-know-the-truth-about-salt.html?pagewanted=all&_r=2&)
- [Scientific American: It's Time to End the War on Salt](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/its-time-to-end-the-war-on-salt/)

The links indicate that there isn't a real long-term relationship between salt and high blood pressure. They do support a short-term blood pressure/salt relationship (salt increases blood pressure), but then so does, in the short term, exercise and caffeine.

Is there a reason why salt is labelled as having a long-term negative impact on blood pressure?